# Mensagem não 100% traduzida

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Quando o usuário não está logado, em qualquer página de pergunta aparece a mensagem abaixo:

```
Stack Overflow em Português é um site de perguntas e respostas para professional and enthusiast programmers. É 100% gratuito e não requer registro.
```

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/734/slogan-homepage-mal-traduzido e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/634/traduzir-a-descricao-do-site e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/traducao-incompleta-no-tour-do-site e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/617/pagina-inicial-tem-traducao-incompleta estamos aguardando a tradução de todos esses lugares. Não sei se todas não deveriam ser fechadas como duplicatas já que trata do mesmo problema, apesar de ser em lugares diferentes.

Comment: É a quinta vez que esta mesma tradução está sendo reportada... é só dar uma pesquisadinha antes para não repetir. Ver também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles?cb=1